# Sanitize & desanitize multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following class I wrote:

```
class Sanitizer {

    public function sanitizeSingle ($string) {  
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $string = stripslashes($string);
        }

        return trim(htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES)); 
    }

    public function sanitize ($string) {
        if (is_array($string)) {
            foreach ($string as $k => $v) {
                $string[$k] = $this->sanitizeSingle($v);
            }
        }
        else {
            $string = $this->sanitizeSingle($string);
        }

        return $string;
    }

    public function desanitize ($string) {
        return trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES));
    }

}
```

The problem is that while it works on strings and one-dimensional arrays, I get the following error with multidimensional arrays:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
>   given in C:\wamp\www\classes\Sanitizer.php on line 10

How do I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was not evaluating array in `$v`
Modify your foreach block like this, this modification will sanitize any level of nested array,

```
 foreach ($string as $k => $v) {
        if(is_array($v))
        {
            $string[$k] = $this->sanitize($v);
        }
        else
        {
            $string[$k] = $this->sanitizeSingle($v);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

With some minor adjustments, you can leverage a [native recursive function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to sanitize scalar values at any level in your array.

```
array_walk_recursive($data, [$this, 'sanitizeSingle']);
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7drYO))

```
class Sanitizer {
    public function sanitizeSingle(&$string) {  
        if (function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $string = stripslashes($string);
        }
        $string = trim(htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES)); 
    }

    public function sanitize($data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            array_walk_recursive($data, [$this, 'sanitizeSingle']);  // replace your loop with this line
        } else {
            $this->sanitizeSingle($data);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

$array = ['one' => ['a ', ' b ', ' c'], 'two' => " <a href='test'>Test</a>"];
$string = ' another "test"';

$sanitizer = new Sanitizer();
var_export($sanitizer->sanitize($array));
echo "\n---\n";
var_export($sanitizer->sanitize($string));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'one' => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c',
  ),
  'two' => '&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;',
)
---
'another &quot;test&quot;'
```

`sanitizeSingle()` modifies the input string by reference so any adjustments are declared upon the variable and there is no `return` value.

`sanitize()` does not modify by reference; the modified data is `return`ed.

Comment: I have no idea why my correct, unique, insightful, demonstrated, explained answer has been given a negative vote.  If it is because `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc()`, well, when this answer was posted this error didn't exist (and that function call was the choice of the OP).  It is irresponsible and misleading to give correct answers negative vote tallies.

Comment: This does not work with common sanitization functions as the sanitization function must accept a value by reference and modify the parameter's variable.

Comment: This answer was crafted for the OP within the scope of the OP's usage and pre-existing class.  The OP's methods all `return` values.  I don't follow your argument.  If you have different requirements,  the script can be adjusted for that.